# Redirect to submenu and hide menu link in submenus

Tags: wordpress, menu, submenu

So I have this code:

```
add_action('admin_menu', function() {

    add_menu_page(
        'Theme options',
        'Theme options', 
        'manage_options', 
        'ef-theme-options',
        'ef_theme_options_display', 
        'dashicons-admin-site' 
    );

    add_submenu_page(
        'ef-theme-options',
        'E-shop options',
        'E-shop options',
        'manage_options',
        'ef-eshop-options',
        'ef_eshop_options_display'
    );
});
```

This results in:

```
Theme options
- Theme options
- E-shop options
```

Is there easy way to redirect to first submenu if menu is clicked, and hide repeating submenu? Is there wordpress functionality that allows for this kind of manipulations?

Answer (score 2):

Figured out myself. Adding remove_submenu after adding submenus functions removes first submenu and wp makes redirect to first real sumenu:

```
remove_submenu_page('ef-theme-options', 'ef-theme-options');
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_submenu_page

Answer (score 0):

```
add_submenu_page(
        null,//give that parent slug to null then it will hide from sidebar
        'E-shop options',
        'E-shop options',
        'manage_options',
        'ef-eshop-options',
        'ef_eshop_options_display'
    );
```